# How many buffers can be added in advance for waveForm input (mmeapi)?

Tags: windows, go, winapi, audio-recording

I'm writing audio streaming app for Windows using MMEAPI and waveIn* functions. Last time I touched that API 20+ years ago so I can't quite remember the semantics.
So what I do is setup a `waveInProc` callback, then call `waveInOpen` then allocate recording buffers and fill `WAVEHDR` structure for each of them. I'm then supposed to call `waveInPrepareHeader` and `waveInAddBuffer` on each WAVEHDR, calling that pair of funcs same number of times as the number of buffers I allocated, right? And then `waveInStart`, of course.
My problem is that Windows 10 only lets me add ONE buffer at a time. Say, I have two. I add 0th, it says OK, I add 1st and it returns 33 (error "still playing") even though I didn't call `waveInStart` yet. It lets me add next buffer only after the previous one is filled with recordings. And even if I run `waveInStart` first and add buffers after that it still only lets me add only one until previous is done.
The recording itself seems to work though, I'm just worrying about gaps in audio stream if I'm forced to use only one underlying buffer at a time.

I don't remember that MMEAPI behavior being the case with Windows 2000/XP. Am I missing something?

UPD.
Code as requested
https://github.com/UrsusArctos/mickey

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Showed. I'm not really sure it's going to help. Writing that kind of app in Go is sort of unorthodox tbh

Comment: WAVERR_STILLPLAYING
The buffer pointed to by the pwh parameter is still in the queue.
Whitch function returns error 33? waveInAddBuffer or waveInUnprepareHeader? It is only allowed to unprepare when the buffer is no longer in use by the API.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT At first I call `StartRecording()` method which calls `queueRecBuffer(0)` and `queueRecBuffer(1)`. `queueRecBuffer()` calls `waveInPrepareHeader` and, if successful, calls `waveInAddBuffer`. It's for the second one that a call to `waveInAddBuffer` returns 33, even though recording hasn't even started yet!

Comment: @Barvinok, the order of wave api calls in your code seems correct to me.  Can you try that code on another computer or another sound card (because it's possibly a driver issue)

Comment: @dsp_user checked that already. I have 3 audio input devices on my PC -- one integrated analog audio card and two external USB sound devices (headset + webcam). This happens for all of them, so it's not the reason.
I'm thinking of rewriting MWE in pure C to see if I got the semantics wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a mistake in my code. Serious but hard to spot mistake, especially in a language not suitable for WinAPI programming.
I'm going to delete the repository but in case anyone is interested what happened, here's the relevant snippet.

```go
func (wmic *TWinMicrophone) queueRecBuffer(index uint8) {
    wmic.initWaveHDR(index)
    ret0, ret1, ret2 := wmic.callProc(waveInPrepareHeader,
        uintptr(wmic.hWaveIn),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&wmic.waveHDR[wmic.recBufIndex])),
        uintptr(unsafe.Sizeof(wmic.waveHDR[wmic.recBufIndex])))
    if ret0 == 0 {
        ret10, ret11, ret12 := wmic.callProc(waveInAddBuffer,
            uintptr(wmic.hWaveIn),
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&wmic.waveHDR[wmic.recBufIndex])),
            uintptr(unsafe.Sizeof(wmic.waveHDR[wmic.recBufIndex])))
```

See the waveHDR structures are being indexed with `wmic.recBufIndex` instead of `index` function parameter.
I feel stupid.
But now the error is gone.
Thank you all for your efforts and attention.